# Monitor progress in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I'd like to create a progress bar for a program that I wrote with OpenCL.

Is there a way, to emit some kind of signal from the kernel, if one work-item is completed?
Or any way, to show the progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to know how many Work-Groups/Items have completed the execution.

If you need a progress bar is probably because it is either VERY slow, or you have a lot of data to process.
If your OpenCL app is very slow I would suggest you to optimize it, since it shouldn't take more than 1 second to complete a call.

However, if you have a lot of data to process, then you can split up the work in small chunks. Then you can track the completion of these chunks.

Comment: I agree. Ideally your kernel shouldn't run for more than a few dozen milliseconds or it can mess with GUI operation. You are better off making many small kernel executions and use an Event for each one; that will give you your progress indication.

Comment: I disagree. many serious GPU codes runs more than just a few seconds. a progress bar is a really useful feature for heavy-duty simulations. This feature was well supported on CUDA, but not OpenCL, vary sad.

Comment: Good advice in general, but often you will run your OpenCL kernel on emulator devices which may run orders of magnitude slower than the real devices. Then progress monitoring becomes very useful.

Answer (score 1):

A not-so-robust solution is to use a host_ptr variable, using the CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR flag, let the kernel to modify the pointer, then on the host side, use a while loop to test this pointer and use the value to print progress bar,

here is the declaration
https://github.com/fangq/mcxcl/blob/master/src/mcx_host.cpp#L428-L431

here is the update inside the kernel
https://github.com/fangq/mcxcl/blob/master/src/mcx_core.cl#L845-L848

here is the host-side value retrieval and progress bar printing
https://github.com/fangq/mcxcl/blob/master/src/mcx_host.cpp#L583-L606

this works ok on AMD GPUs (the update is somewhat sparse, the progress variable is only updated a few times during the kernel runtime, causing non-even jump in the progress bar). however, for nvidia and intel devices, this does not print anything until the kernel is complete.

try my code here

```
git clone https://github.com/fangq/mcxcl.git
cd mcxcl/src
make clean all
cd ../example/quicktest
./run_qtest.sh -D P
```

I asked this question on NVIDIA's forum, but no one knows how to fix it for nvidia.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1031335/cuda-programming-and-performance/how-to-update-host-memory-variable-from-device-to-host-during-kernel-execution-in-opencl/